Question about Definition 5.7 of Do Carmo's "Riemmanian Geometry"
I have been reading through Definition 5.7 of Do Carmo's Riemmanian Geometry, but am having trouble understanding why the two circled terms below are equal:

I am guessing that a proof would involve the covariant derivative in some way, but am unsure exactly how. Any insight would be deeply appreciated :)

From the product rule, it follows that
$$\frac{d}{dt}T_{i_1\cdots i_r}(t)=\partial_tT_{i_1\cdots i_r}(\alpha(t)) e_{i_1}(t)\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_r}(t) + T_{i_1\cdots i_r}(\alpha(t))\partial_t\left(e_{i_1}(t)\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_r}(t)\right),$$
but the second term vanishes because the basis is parallel along $\alpha(t)$ (applying the product rule again for each element of the basis).  Thus, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dt}T_{i_1\cdots i_r}(t)= \alpha_\ell'(t)\partial_\ell T_{i_1\cdots i_r}(\alpha(t)) e_{i_1}(t)\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_r}(t) = Z_\ell(\alpha(t)) \partial_\ell T_{i_1\cdots i_r}(t),$$
which is the coordinate representation of $Z(T(e_{i_1}(t),\cdots, e_{i_r}(t))).$
